# Delete 'Permanent' Changes to PATH?

Tags: macos, bash, path

I am developing using Cocos2d-x on a Mac running OS X 10.11.6.  I have installed Android Studio and have a number of new entries in my PATH which are NOT being added by my .bash_profile. Example '/Users/MyName/Library/Android/sdk/tools'.

I want to build using another version of the SDK downloaded to another directory.  I can add the path to the other SDK to my .bash_profile Ok but the previous path entries interfere.  I cannot find whereabouts these are added to the PATH so I might remove them.

You may guess something of a MAC newbie.  Any clues appreciated?

AndyF.

Answer (score 0):

You can put needed path **before** any other path in `PATH`.

`export PATH=/path/to/dir:$PATH`

This will force your path to first look to `/path/to/dir` to resolve and you'll get needed version.